# New To Python Having Trouble with boolean logic

Tags: python

This My Assignment
You are provided with a person’s age and you need to determine which school level the person falls within.

```
If 6 to 11 output ‘primary school’
If 12 to 18 output ‘secondary school’
If neither, then output ‘NA’
```

This is My code

```
import sys
age= int(sys.argv[1])

if age >= 6.0 and age <=11:
  print ('primary school')
if age >=12 and age <=18:
  print ('secondary school')
if age < 6.0 and age >18: 
  print ('NA')
```

This is my error
Program Output

```
Program Failed for Input: 5
Expected Output: NA
Your Program Output:
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Carefully read your last if statement. You might also want to consider using an elif and else

Comment: After you fix your problem try to figure out where someone 11.5 years old should be placed.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski That guy will be `ValueError`'ed out of this program :)

Comment: @schwobaseggl: Ah! I was fooled by the comparison to `6.0` that he had float values and totally missed the call to `int()`.

Answer (score 3):

You need an `or`:

```
if age < 6 or age > 18:
```

`age` cannot be less than `6` **and** greater than `18` at the same time. Moreover, you can avoid the last condition altogether by using an `if-elif-else` structure and chain the inequations:

```
if 6 <= age <= 11:
    print('primary school')
elif 12 <= age <= 18:
    print ('secondary school')
else: 
    print ('NA')
```

Comment: You can also suggest to use `elif`.

Comment: Also you need to convert the `sys.argv` value from string to int (or appropriate) type.

Answer (score 0):

The age value can not be inferior to 6 and superior to 18 at the same time

```
if age<6 or age>18:
    print ("NA")
```